# pack empty directory with SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, zip

I want to pack to zip some folder using SharpZipLib. Example stucture

```
directory1:
    directory2:
         file1
    file2
    directory3:
        directory4:
```

When I pack it using c# code from here:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx#Create_a_Zip_with_full_control_over_contents_0

I get zip archives without `directory3` and `directory4`.

My question is how can I pack to get archives with `directory3` and `directory4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 FastZip fastZip = new FastZip();

 fastZip.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;
 // Include all files by recursing through the directory structure
 bool recurse = true; 
 // Dont filter any files at all 
 string filter = null;
 fastZip.CreateZip("fileName.zip", @"C:\SourceDirectory", recurse, filter);
```

one caveat is that it can't handle UTF-8 file names.

Here is the link to the documentation wiki:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200221081153/https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip

Comment: Only name can't using utf-8 or content too? Can I pack file with name `aa.txt` which is utf-8 text file?

Comment: @nirmus - just the file names.

Comment: thanks a lot, now in zip I have the empty directory, but if I use FastZip.ExtractZip there isn't the empty directory;) interesting;p

Comment: @nirmus- do the same before u extracting.                      `FastZip fs = new FastZip();
fs.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;   fs.ExtractZip(destinationFile, unpackedPath, null);`

Answer (score 4):

You can make the program add the folders as entries.

Add the code below on the loop for each folder.

```
//Here we create a path for a new entry,
//but this time with the '\' in the end, its a folder
string sEntry = sFolder.Substring(iFolderOffset) + "\\";
sEntry = ZipEntry.CleanName(sEntry);
ZipEntry zeOutput = new ZipEntry(sEntry);
zsOutput.PutNextEntry(zeOutput);
zsOutput.CloseEntry();
```

I didn't test the unzipping yet.